According to the New York prosecution, how did Trump unlawfully influence the election?
According to the Wikipedia article on The People of the State of New York v. Donald J. Trump (emphasis mine):

The Manhattan District Attorney (DA), Alvin Bragg, accused Trump of falsifying these business records with the intent to commit other crimes: violation of federal campaign finance limits, unlawfully influencing the 2016 U.S. presidential election, and tax fraud.

What exactly did the prosecution accuse Trump of doing that unlawfully influenced the election?
What I've researched so far:
The Wikipedia article references the election a lot, but I couldn't find what exactly the prosecution said that Trump did to influence the election unlawfully.
This answer suggests that it is not illegal to pay someone to keep quiet ahead of an election, so the hush money payments themselves don't seem to have been illegal.
That answer also suggests that Cohen's actions were illegal because the hush money payments were not properly reported in campaign finance reports. So it's possible that improper campaign finance reporting is what would make the election influence unlawful. However, that answer specifically says that Cohen wasn't charged with "unduly" influencing the election, so it sounds like the illegal reporting is distinct from unlawful election influence.

I am very frustrated with StackExchange's search function. I did in fact look for an existing answer to my question before asking it

The other question is distinctly different from this one.  Voting to reopen.

There seems to be over-zealousness on SE about closing questions. Often questions are closed as duplicates and the 'duplicates' cited are not duplicates at all, but an answer to the alleged duplicate question can be culled from those cited as already asked. And then the unjustified downvotes begin. It's gotten to the point that I am very reluctant to ask a question at all, for fear that someone may decide that the answer to my question can be deduced from answers to other questions, a cascade of downvotes ensues along with the question being closed.

@Vector That's why in addition to votes to close, there are also votes to reopen.  In my experience, a reopened question usually stays open.  Now the system isn't enough to deal with a wholly rotten site of users of sufficient rep, but even supposing a question fails to reopen that objectively should the more likely explanation is lack of visibility, rather than any sort of collective malice or kneejerk incompetence. But for what it's worth, Politics and Law SE's have both become very familiar with huge amounts of vitriol, trolling, and other bad behaviors with Trump-related questions.

In this case, I would say that the actual answer to your question is Jen's answer on this Q&A.  The short of the matter being that the prosecution did not have to prove Trump attempted or succeeded in influencing the election through particular unlawful means. So no such specific accusations really exist.

Additionally, failure of a search to show you a duplicate, leading to your Q&A being marked as a duplicate, is a feature and a boon, not a failure of yourself or the site.  The whole point is to help people find answers to their questions.  But the form of that question can be highly variable.  Duplicate Q&A's increase the chances that the way a person asks the question exists and will direct them towards a suitable answer.

@zibadawatimmy I agree that Jen's answer that you linked answers my question better than the current duplicate. Is there a way to change which question my question is marked as a duplicate of?

@THummus Yes, going by the fact that it's now added to the duplicates. The "flag" link on the bottom left of the question is probably sufficient for notifying those of sufficient privilege levels, should it be relevant again in the future.

@THummus I agree, I use normally google for the SE with a "site:stackexchange.com" suffix. That can search on all SE sites.
